# смена игрока при переходе на другую сцену unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d

есть две сцены. на одной один главный игрок со своими скриптами, на другой - другой. как сделать, чтобы когда с первой сцены переходишь на вторую управление менялось на игрока второй сцены, а не оставалось с первой?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

кажется, разобрался). моя проблема была в том, что я не сохранил перса со второй сцены как префаб. теперь, вроде норм

Answer (score 0):

Можете проверять сцену с помощью ID

```cs
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

int currentScene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;
```

Можете получить любую информацию об активной сцене с помощью

```cs
SceneManager.GetActiveScene()
```